# Extracting text from an article, how filter tags in a div?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

We are using scrapy and want to get the body of an article that is located in a specific div. So we wrote this:

```
article['body'] = response.xpath('string(//div[@itemprop="articleBody"])').extract_first()
```

The problem is that sometimes we get undesired text.
For example  we got this text from a style tag located in our div:
"#container_14931537823{\n\t\tpadding:5px 5px 0px 10px;"

We can parse the article with beautifulsoup but we'll get the same result:

```
article['body'] = ''.join(soup.find_all('div',attrs={"itemprop" : "articleBody"})[0].text)
```

We cacth the div where all the text body is located and then we apply a method (string or text) that extract and concatenate our text but is it possible to exclude tags undesired in this div?
Are we force to wrote a function to clear the text extracted?

Comment: what is the website url ?

Comment: Scrapy has a [library](https://github.com/scrapy/w3lib/blob/master/w3lib/html.py) `w3lib` for removing tags. You can use it with Item Loaders [example](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html?highlight=w3lib#declaring-input-and-output-processors).

Comment: The url: http://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/article/2017/04/26/europe-macron-emploi-la-trumpisation-de-marine-le-pen-sur-tf1_5117479_4355770.html

Comment: I'm looking how item loaders works, feedback soon.

Comment: Have difficulties to understand item loader context, if someone have a good link or tutorial :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all text from that article without `script` tag if you use xpath function [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/not)  and amend your xpath expression to:

```
article['body'] = ''.join(response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="articleBody"]/*[not(script)]//text()').extract())
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, syntax error: invalid character in identifier

Comment: Please copy and try again. I edited my xpath expression it had some invisible blank space. Now it should [work](http://icecream.me/cb9769ee203ef37a9a55e87479ce98d4).

Answer (score 1):

If you want **all** tags removed you could try using xpath's `text()` function instead:

```
article['body'] = response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="articleBody"]//text()').extract_first()
```

It works quite well unless there are tags with Javascript inside.

Comment: We want to remove just undesired tags that contains that kind of text: "\nrequire(['highcharts/4.1.9','highcharts-standalone'], function() {\n\n\t//FONCTIONS GLOBALES\n\tHighcharts.setOptions({\n\..."